# Absolute convergence series laws II (help with a proof)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Hi everyone this is easy I think. My question is regarding to the next proof.

[I've shown that if $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)$ and  $\sum _{x\in X}g(x)$  are both absolutely convergent then $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)+g(x)$ is absolutely convergent. Furthermore, 
$$\sum _{x\in X}f(x)+g(x)= \sum _{x\in X}f(x)+\sum _{x\in X}g(x)$$]

Let $X$ be a set and let $f: X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)$ is absolutely convergent. If $X= X_1\cup X_2$ and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \varnothing $, then $\sum _{x\in X_i}f(x)$ [for $i=1, 2$] is absolutely convergent and

$$\sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2}f(x)=\sum _{x\in X_1}f(x)+\sum _{x\in X_2}f(x)$$

Conversely, if $h:  X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum _{x\in X_1}f(x)$ and $\sum _{x\in X_2}f(x)$ are absolutely convergent, then $\sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2 } f(x)$ is also absolutely convergent  and

$$\sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2}h(x)=\sum _{x\in X_1}h(x)+\sum _{x\in X_2}h(x)$$

Proof: Let $F\subset X_1$ and $\#F < \infty$. Since $F\subset X$ and is finite then we have:

$$\sum _{x\in F}|f(x)|\in \bigg \{\sum _{x\in A}|f(x)|: A\subset X;\, \#A < \infty \bigg \} $$

This means that $\sum _{x\in F}|f(x)|$ is at most the least upper bound which is less than infinity. Then any finite subset of $X_1$ is bounded and hence is absolutely convergent. The same argument works for $X_2$.

It is not difficult to show $\sum _{x\in X_1}f(x)= \sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2}1_{X_1}(f(x))$ and similarly for $X_2$. Where  $1_E (x) :=
\begin{cases}
1, &  x\in E\\
0, &  x\notin E
\end{cases}$ is the indicator function.

Then

$$\sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2}1_{X_1}(f(x))+\sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2}1_{X_2}(f(x))=\sum _{x\in X_1\cup X_2}1_{X_1}(f(x))+1_{X_2}(f(x))$$

But $1_{X_1}(f(x))+1_{X_2}(f(x)) = f(x)$ and thus the claim follows.

For the converse I may assume that $X_1, X_2$ are disjoint sets, otherwise the claim does not have sense at least for me.

Let $F\subset X_1\cup X_2$ and $\#F<\infty$. Then

\begin{align} \sum _{x\in F}|h(x)|=\sum _{x\in (X_1\cap F) \cup (X_2\cap F) }|h(x)|
& =\sum _{x\in X_1\cap F }|h(x)|+\sum _{x\in X_2\cap F }|h(x)|\\
& \le \sup _{A\subset X1;\, \#A < \infty} \sum _{x\in A}|h(x)| +\sup_{B\subset X2; \,\#B < \infty} \sum _{x\in B}|h(x)| 
\end{align}

Then is absolutely convergent. And we can use the same trick as above to conclude the proof.

So, do you think the proof is correct? Any suggestion? What do you think guys? I think is a easy way to do it? Am I right? Please any help would be great. Thanks in advance.